# MVC Razor RC 1: Can the @section be defined with a string constant?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any way to use a string on a page using a master layout and calling a section?

So instead of this:

```
  @section SomeSection
```

I could do this?

```
  @section "SomeString"
```

Or better

```
  @section SomeClass.SomeConstantString
```

Reason for this?  So that I can use a constant string on the master page for the section name and use the same constant string on the partial page.

```
  @RenderSection(eClass.SomeConstantString, required:false)
```

I'm really hoping there is a way to do this otherwise it seems like an issue overall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. I don't see that as that big of a limitation because if the layout is rendering a required section and the names do not match you'll het an error at runtime.

Comment: Well the reason being is keeping control of how many changes are involved if the name changes on the master page.  All about keeping things consistent to avoid runtime errors.

Comment: Sure, I understan, but given the design of the `@section` this simply won't work because the section is treated as a literal and it would be impossible to determine if it's a string or a reference to a variable or field.